# sich durchhacken oder sich durch hacken?

Tags: reformed-orthography, separable-verb

Zwangsweise muß ich mich langsam, widerwillig, aber unerbittlicherweise den Tatsachen der neuen Rechtschreibung stellen. Glücklicherweise gibt es automatische Rechtschreibprüfungen.

Bei folgendem Fall versagt aber die Automatik...

Alte Rechtschreibung:

> Durch eine Schicht Eis kann man sich durchhacken oder durchschmelzen.

Muß ich das in neuer Rechtschreibung trennen?

> Durch eine Schicht Eis kann man sich durch hacken oder durch schmelzen.

Meine Rechtschreibprüfung gibt mir beide Möglichkeiten... aber nach NDR kann wohl nicht *beides* richtig sein?!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich denke, da greift die [Duden-Regel 48](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#K48):

> Zusammensetzungen mit Verben können gelegentlich aus denselben oder ähnlichen Wörtern bestehen wie getrennt geschriebene Wortgruppen. Bei den Zusammensetzungen aus Adverb und Verb ist das Adverb meist deutlich stärker betont als das Verb. [...]
>
> *Beispiele:*
>
> Wir sind noch einmal davọngekommen.
>
> *Aber:* Die Flecken sind davon gekommen, dass ...
>
> Die Richterin hat ihn freigesprochen.
>
> *Aber:* Sie hat frei gesprochen (ohne Manuskript).

In Deinem Fall:

> Wenn man in einer Eishöhle gefangen ist, kann man sich **durch Hacken** befreien, also indem man sich durch die Eisschicht **durchhackt**.

Der Grund, weswegen Deine Rechtschreibprüfung beide Varianten akzeptiert, ist wohl, dass alle von Dir verwendeten Wörter im Wörterbuch vorhanden sind. Ob sie an der Stelle sinnvoll eingesetzt sind, kann die Rechtschreibprüfung nicht erkennen. Da könnte Dir die Grammatikprüfung weiterhelfen, falls Du eine gute hast.

Comment: So hat's mir mein Sprachgefühl auch geflüstert, aber dem traue ich bei der neuen RS nicht. Alter Gaul lernt keine neuen Tricks...